# No Ubuntu boot option in grub after installing Windows 7

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.10, boot-repair

I installed Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu 14.10 and hence I lost grub. I reinstalled grub using a liveCD and now the Ubuntu boot option only shows `Windows 7` and 10s timer after which it'll boot into Windows 7. It doesn't show Ubuntu option. I tried repairing boot using `boot-repair` tool but no luck.

Here's the `boot-repair` pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9834084/

Answer (score -1):

You can start on a live ubuntu (usb disk or cd)
and launch

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot (without the live inserted)

---

If it don't work, you can force a reinstall with purge
like this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-pc grub-common
```